# DB2-400 MCH-1210 'receiver too small to hold result' in module QQQQUERY subroutine BUILDAP

Tags: db2-400

Occasionaly we get the following message 
from module QQQQUERY in procedure BUILDAP.

*MCH1210 Receiver value too small to hold result.*

```
                                 Van module  . . . . . . . . :   QQQQUERY
                                 Van procedure . . . . . . . :   BUILDAP
                                 Instructie  . . . . . . . . :   24041
                                 Naar module . . . . . . . . :   QQQQUERY
                                 Naar procedure  . . . . . . :   BUILDAP
                                 Instructie  . . . . . . . . :   24041
                                 Bericht . . . . :   Receiver value too small to hold result.
```

Extra log info

```
MCH1210 Escape 40 11/04/18 10:33:28,661097 QQQQUERY QSYS *STMT QQQQUERY QSYS *STMT
Van module . . . . . . . . : QQQQUERY
Van procedure . . . . . . . : BUILDAP
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 24041
Naar module . . . . . . . . : QQQQUERY
Naar procedure . . . . . . : BUILDAP
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 24041
Bericht . . . . : Receiver value too small to hold result.
CPF4204 Escape 50 11/04/18 10:33:28,697990 QQQQUERY QSYS *STMT LOGGING2 SOARETPGM *STMT
Van module . . . . . . . . : QQQQUERY
Van procedure . . . . . . . : QQQQUERY
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 34332
Naar module . . . . . . . . : LOGGING2
Naar procedure . . . . . . : LOGGING2
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 1000001
Bericht . . . . : Er is een interne storing opgetreden in de queryprocessor.
Oorzaak . . . . : er is een systeemfout opgetreden in het programma van de
queryprocessor. Het nummer van het querydefinitiesjabloon (QDT) is 0.
Recovery . . . : raadpleeg de berichten van lager niveau. Verbeter
eventuele fouten en geef de opdracht opnieuw op. Als het probleem zich
opnieuw voordoet, meldt u het probleem met de opdracht ANZPRB (Problemen
analyseren).
RNX1216 Escape 99 11/04/18 10:33:28,828323 QRNXIE QSYS *STMT LOGGING2 SOARETPGM *STMT
Van module . . . . . . . . : QRNXMSG
Van procedure . . . . . . . : SignalException
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 21
Naar module . . . . . . . . : LOGGING2
Naar procedure . . . . . . : LOGGING2
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 1000001
Bericht . . . . : Error message CPF4204 appeared during OPEN for file
FALOGBL0.
Cause . . . . . : RPG procedure LOGGING2 in program SOARETPGM/LOGGING2
received the message CPF4204 while performing an implicit OPEN operation on
file FALOGBL0. The actual file is FALOGBL0. Recovery . . . : Check the
job log for a complete description of message CPF4204, and contact the
person responsible for program maintenance. If the file has a device type of
SPECIAL, there may be no message in the job log.
RNQ1216 Kopie afzender 99 11/04/18 10:33:28,838222 QRNXIE QSYS *STMT QRNXIE QSYS *STMT
Van module . . . . . . . . : QRNXMSG
Van procedure . . . . . . . : InqMsg
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 8
Naar module . . . . . . . . : QRNXMSG
Naar procedure . . . . . . : InqMsg
Instructie . . . . . . . . : 8
Bericht . . . . : Error message CPF4204 appeared during OPEN for file
FALOGBL0 (C S D F).
Cause . . . . . : RPG procedure LOGGING2 in program SOARETPGM/LOGGING2
received the message CPF4204 while performing an implicit OPEN operation on
file FALOGBL0. The actual file is FALOGBL0. Recovery . . . : Check the
job log for a complete description of message CPF4204, and contact the
person responsible for program maintenance. If the file has a device type of
SPECIAL, there may be no message in the job log. Possible choices for
replying to message . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : D – Obtain RPG
formatted printout of system storage. S – Obtain printout of system
storage. F – Obtain full formatted printout of system storage. C – Cancel.
```

And this occurs in a triggerprogram that we use for logging changes.
The triggertime is *after and event is *update & *insert & *delete.

The problem occurs when starting the program and ultimatly gives a CPF4204 msg during opening the logical which contains the logged data.

It has occurred on several files we log.

Any suggestions where to look?
Tx

Comment: Can you show us source for procedure `BUILDAP`, and maybe the relevant portion of the job log generated with `LOG(4 00 *SECLVL)`?

Comment: the procedure BUILDAP is in a PGM of os400 (don't know if it's from a specific ptf) and is located in QSYS. Is there a possibility to get the source from that PGM?
Unfortunatly the spooledfile has been deleted by the user, but I have updated the question with a partial log.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me, there are various APARs in this sort of area I see (although none matching this specific issue). Are you up to date re database group PTF? (P.S. BUILDAP appears to be part of the operating system.)

Comment: All latest ptf's have been installed and applied. The error has occured once after installation. We are probably going to alter our program and check if we can catch the error and then log somewhere else, with less info.